# Graph theory, random vertex connect to create largest tree

Tags: tree, graph-theory

I'm looking for a point in the right direction or a possible algorithm to solve this problem.

I have a graph with some number of vertices connected. Picking any random vertex that's not already fully connected, choose an edge to connect that will create, or go towards creating, the largest tree. (Call this a **run**.) "Go towards creating" means to minimize the number of runs expected to create the largest tree.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiUF5.png

This image has examples of two possible runs. The first run is simple since it just picks the edge to connect to the only tree in the graph. The second run picks the upward edge because it is closer to the tree than picking the bottom edge.

There are other cases where there could be multiple trees already on the graph. The chosen edge should still follow the principle of trying to create the largest tree in the fewest amount of runs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mCRx.png

I've been looking at Minimum Spanning Tree ignoring weights, but I'm still having some difficulty. The part that I can't wrap my head around is the random vertex and each run being greedy.

Comment: What is a "largest tree"? If you want to maximize the weight of the chosen edges - why not just multiply all of them by -1 and use any MST algorithm? Also, I'm not sure what the problem with "the random vertex" is. Why would you choose your vertex at random? Or is that part of the input, i.e., you have no control over the order in which the vertices must be added? But even then: Compute an MST on the graph, and when a vertex is "randomly selected", just select one of its incident edges in the MST.

Comment: @LukasBarth Largest tree means the number of vertices that are connected. The first image would have a tree of size 4. Second image has two trees of size 4 and size 3. And yes, the input is a random graph with any amount of vertices already connected, and a random vertex. I have to decide on the best edge. I've looked over it a little more and I'm not sure MST is the right approach anymore since all of the edges have equal weight, and the tree in the first image isn't minimal.